# How can I animate scale and rotation of d3-geo projection at the same time with different durations and ease functions?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, d3-geo

The title is pretty descriptive of my question. I'm trying to find the most idiomatic/easy way to animate the scale and rotation property of a d3-geo projection (https://d3js.org/d3-geo/projection).

I'm fairly new to d3, so I don't know all the tools at my disposal yet, so please point me in a good direction if you have any answers/ideas. I'm also using React, so if that adds any complexity in your answer, please let me know.

My current attempt is using d3.tween() to manual call a function every tick t, that updates my current projection function and calls a function to redraw my Canvas. This works fine, but it doesn't allow me to use interpolations with different ease functions as I have both scale and rotation within the same .tween().

A trimmed version of my code:

```
/* input as array of arrays of form ["type", [interpolation range], duration, startTime] */
d3.transition()
      .duration(longestAnimation)
      .ease(d3.easePolyInOut)
      .tween("", function (d) {
        const interpolations = {};
        animationArray.forEach((animation) => {
          const [
            type,
            [interpolationStartVal, interpolationEndVal],
            duration,
            startTime,
          ] = animation;
          //console.log(animation);
          interpolations[animation] = [
            d3.interpolate(interpolationStartVal, interpolationEndVal),
            duration,
            startTime,
            type,
          ];
        });
        return function (t) {
          Object.entries(interpolations).forEach((interpolation) => {
            const [key, [interpolationFunc, duration, startTime, type]] =
              interpolation;
            const endTime = startTime + duration;
            let additionalFrame = false;
            if (startTime / longestAnimation <= t) {
              additionalFrame = true;
            }

            if (
              (startTime / longestAnimation <= t &&
                endTime / longestAnimation >= t) ||
              additionalFrame
            ) {
              if (endTime / longestAnimation >= t) additionalFrame = false;
              const newProjection = projection;
              const tempT = Math.min(endTime / longestAnimation, t);
              if (type === "rotate") {
              
                newProjection.rotate(
                  interpolationFunc(
                    (tempT - startTime / longestAnimation) *
                      (longestAnimation / duration)
                  )
                );
              }

              if (type === "scale") {
                newProjection.scale(
                  projectionScale *
                    interpolationFunc(
                      (tempT - startTime / longestAnimation) *
                        (longestAnimation / duration)
                    )
                );
              }
              drawCanvasFunc.current(newProjection);
```

This piece is a little long, but I wanted to illustrate the general idea I had so far, where I edit the current projection and then redraw the canvas every tick. Again, this works fine, but I can't use different easing functions.

Is my only option to write my own animation function using d3.timer?

Let me know - thanks a lot!